Angular regex validator allows empty value, while the regex clause should demand at least one digit
I am having this error and I wonder if I am doing something wrong here or it is the component not working. I am working in typescript, angular 17.
In my Formgroup I am specifying this:
limitsForm = new FormGroup({inputLimit: new FormControl('', [Validators.pattern('[0-9]+')])});

Then if I leave the field empty, my form group is valid according to 'this.limitsForm.valid'. I explicitly have to add 'Validators.required' and then the form is invalid when you leave the input empty. But I think the regex '[0-9]+' indicates one or more numbers, so it should fail without the required validator. Now I am patching it like:
limitsForm = new FormGroup({inputLimit: new FormControl('', [Validators.pattern('[0-9]+'), Validators.required])});

But I think the 'Validators.required' should not be necessary! Is this wrong working of the angular component? Or is my understanding of regex not correct?

The regex pattern is a validation for the content entered in the input field, if you don't enter anything, there is nothing to evaluate. If you click in and then click out without writing anything, how is the regex pattern supposed to work? If you don't want the input to be EMPTY, meaning it is a MANDATORY field, then add the required validator along with the regex pattern

This looks strange at first but works as intended. If the input is empty, the pattern validation is skipped. Here are a few reasons why it makes sense:

Nullable form controls can have null as a value. In this case pattern validation would behave strange. Either the value would need to be transformed to empty string before validation, which feels wrong. Or worse, the value is being coerced to 'null' by JavaScript, which actually would can happen when the value is passed to the RegExp.test() function, and can lead to completely unexpected results. Angular works around this issue by checking if the value is falsy, and skips validation in this case. See the source code.
It is much easier to see at a glance which fields of a form group are required, by searching for Validators.required. Otherwise you would need to read and understand every single pattern used.
Some component libraries like Angular Material automatically add an asterisk to the field's label when the Validators.required validator is added to the form control. With your regex, the asterisk would need to be added manually.

I would suggest you to re-write your regex to allow empty values, and add the required validator, in order to avoid any confusion:
limitsForm = new FormGroup({
  inputLimit: new FormControl('', [
    Validators.pattern('[0-9]*'),
    Validators.required,
  ]),
});


Thank you! When I get comment in the code review why I am adding the required validator, I will use your explication.
